# Algorithm in document class clv2

Tags: document-classes, algorithms

How to write an algorithm in an article in `\documentclass{clv2}`, can anybody send me a working model with dummy algorithm, because I guess `\caption` is creating problem. I want to send it to Computational Linguistics journal by MIT press but it is giving lots of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `algorithm2e` and `algorithmic` with the `clv2` class, provided you smooth out some issues:

1. the class defines an `algorithm` environment (a very primitive one)
2. the class defines `\TRUE`
3. the class defines a `numdef` environment, that makes it incompatible with `etoolbox`

Here's a way to use `algorithm2e` and `algorithmic` with the class.

```
\documentclass{clv2}

%% Remove the useless algorithm environment
\let\algorithm\relax
\let\endalgorithm\relax
%% Remove the useless numdef environment
\let\numdef\relax

\usepackage{algorithm2e,algorithmic,xpatch}

%% the algorithmic package does \newcommand{\TRUE}{...}
\xpretocmd{\algorithmic}{\let\TRUE\relax}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
 \STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
 \STATE $X \leftarrow x$
 \STATE $N \leftarrow n$
 \WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
 \IF{$N$ is even}
 \STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$
 \STATE $N \leftarrow N / 2$
 \ELSE[$N$ is odd]
 \STATE $y \leftarrow y \times X$
 \STATE $N \leftarrow N - 1$
 \ENDIF
 \ENDWHILE
 \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am new in Latex and was not knowing that `%% Remove the useless algorithm environment
\let\algorithm\relax
\let\endalgorithm\relax
%% Remove the useless numdef environment
\let\numdef\relax` this we can do. You won't believe, I am struggling to write the algorithm with nested loops from last 15 days. 15 days, no progress, submission deadline is approaching. Now I think, I will be able to write, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [`clv2` class](http://cljournal.org/Docs/clv2.cls) already defines an `algorithm` environment as a regular list similar to that of `description` (see section **7.1 Other List Types** in the [COLI manual](http://cljournal.org/Docs/COLI-manual1.pdf) or p 3-4 of the [COLI template](http://cljournal.org/Docs/COLI-template.pdf)):

```
\newenvironment{algorithm}{\par\list{}{\leftmargin\z@\labelwidth\z@\labelsep\z@\itemsep6pt\topsep12pt plus2pt
                        \let\makelabel\algorithmlabel}}{\endlist}
\def\algorithmlabel#1{{\bfseries #1: }}
```

As such, it's not a float like one would expect, nor does it automate the enumeration of steps typically associated with an "algorithm". Additionally, there's no place for a `\caption` inside the algorithm. Here's how it should be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{clv2}% http://cljournal.org/Docs/clv2.cls

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \item[1] Something
  \item[b] Something else
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

My suggestion would be to stick to the journal document class and use their `algorithm` environment as-is; that is, don't resort to including other (possibly incompatible) algorithm packages (like [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)).

Comment: But the paper downloaded from their journal has very nicely written algorithms, wondering how they have achieved that. Can we find anywhere, what all types of algorithm styles are compatible with clv2?

Comment: I want to write following algorithm in clv2, please help                              `Main Algorithm: Algo Caption
Data: SDR, TDR
Result: A file                                                                                     begin
Initialize:
ReviewList[] = [Pos, Neg,USource, UTarget];
Perform:
for each i in ReviewList[] do
Input = Input.append(ReviewList[i])
end
call Function 1: PMI 
PMIScore = PMI(Input)
call Function 2: R
Dict = relatedness(PMIScore)
end`

Comment: @userjha: I've created [a paste](http://pastebin.com/tQ3MXD8s) that provides [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yrRVT.png). Perhaps that works for you.

Comment: Great, I am quite happy with the results. One last help, when we use loops, as in this, we used `for loop`, then how to indent further statements to show that the following statements are inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Finally my algorithm in good shape

```
\documentclass{clv2}

%% Remove the useless algorithm environment
\let\algorithm\relax
\let\endalgorithm\relax
%% Remove the useless numdef environment
\let\numdef\relax

\usepackage[lined,ruled,vlined,resetcount]{algorithm2e}

%% the algorithmic package does \newcommand{\TRUE}{...}
%\xpretocmd{\algorithmic}{\let\TRUE\relax}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\BlankLine
\KwData{Input}
\KwResult{PMI}
\BlankLine
\Begin
{
 \textbf{Perform:}\\  
 Token\\     
 \For {each}
{
Pos\\
\If{C}
{
Write
 }
 }
  \For {each}
 {
U= F\\
B= F[i] “+” F[i+1]
}
 \For {each}
{
bbbbb\\
\For {each}
{
    \If {C}                                             {
  bbbb+=1
 }
 \If {C}                                             {
  bbb+=1
  }
  }
  }
 \For {each}
 {
 $
 bbbb
$\
}
}       
\caption{PMI}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```